# How to update a List Item at run time in android?

Tags: android, listview

In my android application I am uploading a files to server using FTP. I have a list of files and I am displaying that is a Listview. When the user selects the list items and hitting upload button it is uploading in that time I want to show the upload progress in selected files. I done with this part but the problem is when I scroll the listview the the progress is showing for different files(not selected for upload). My exact expectation is like the belo image. Please any one help me
[image]

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    final FileItem fItem = files.get(position);
    //if(position!=0){
    if(fItem != null) {
        viewHolder.fNameTextView.setText(fItem.getName());
        if(fItem.getDate() != null) {
            Date lastModifiedDate = fItem.getDate();
            DateFormat formatter = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
            viewHolder.fDateTextView.setText(formatter.format(lastModifiedDate));
        }
        else {
            viewHolder.fDateTextView.setText("");
        }
```

//fItem.getType()
            int fileType = fItem.getType();
            long data = fItem.getData();

```
        if(fileType == Globals.FILE_TYPE_DIRECTORY) {
            if(data <= 1){
                viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText(data+" Item");
            }
            else if(data == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
                viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText("Folder");
            }
            else {
                viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText(data+" Items");
                //viewHolder.fImageviewSelection.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            viewHolder.fIconImageView.setImageResource(Globals.ICON_DIRECTORY);

        }
        else if (fileType == Globals.FILE_TYPE_APPLICATION) {
            viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText(Utilities.getHumanReadableFileSize(data,true));
            viewHolder.fIconImageView.setImageResource(Globals.ICON_APPLICATION);
        }
        else if (fileType == Globals.FILE_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText(Utilities.getHumanReadableFileSize(data,true));
            viewHolder.fIconImageView.setImageResource(Globals.ICON_AUDIO);
        }
        else if (fileType == Globals.FILE_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText(Utilities.getHumanReadableFileSize(data,true));
            viewHolder.fIconImageView.setImageResource(Globals.ICON_IMAGE);
        }
        else if (fileType == Globals.FILE_TYPE_TEXT) {
            viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText(Utilities.getHumanReadableFileSize(data,true));
            viewHolder.fIconImageView.setImageResource(Globals.ICON_TEXT);
        }
        else if (fileType == Globals.FILE_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText(Utilities.getHumanReadableFileSize(data,true));
            viewHolder.fIconImageView.setImageResource(Globals.ICON_VIDEO);
        }
        else if (fileType == Globals.FILE_TYPE_PARENT) {
            viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText("Parent Directory");
            viewHolder.fIconImageView.setImageResource(Globals.ICON_PARENT);

        }
        else if (fileType == Globals.FILE_TYPE_OTHERS) {
            viewHolder.fDataTextView.setText(Utilities.getHumanReadableFileSize(data,true));
            viewHolder.fIconImageView.setImageResource(Globals.ICON_OTHERS);
        }
    }
```

// }
        final CheckBox cb =viewHolder.fImageviewSelection;
        cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (files.get(position).isclicked) {
                    files.get(position).isclicked = false;
                    files.get(position).index=0;
                } else {
                    files.get(position).isclicked = true;
                    files.get(position).index=position;
                }               
        }
    });

    if (files.get(position).isclicked) {
        cb.setChecked(true);           
    }
    else {
        cb.setChecked(false);
    }  


    return view;
}
```

Code for updating the progress

```
                                   final ListView listView = mLocalFileListView;


                                        final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                                        final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

                                        if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
                                             convertView= listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
                                        } else {
                                            final int childIndex = pos- firstListItemPosition;
                                             convertView=listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
                                        }
                                     convertView=listView.getChildAt(pos);


                                    //View convertView = listView.getChildAt(selectedFiles.get(0).getIndex()-first);
                                    if(convertView!=null){                                                                              
                                        ImageView iv=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_list_item_icon);
                                        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        CheckBox cb=(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_list_item_selector);
                                        cb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        TextView tv=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                                        ProgressBar pb=(ProgressBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
                                        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        pb.setProgress(percent);
                                        pb.setSecondaryProgress(percent+10);
                                        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                        tv.setText(percent + "%" ); 
                                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yeah, you would need to provide the problem code

Comment: Which code I want to put here adapter or Activity or both

Comment: Both if they aren't too big. If they are larger start with `getView()` of the adapter and wherever you are showing the progress

Comment: Added the code one more thing the upload code inside synctask